# Generate an npm module from typescript files

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm developing a npm module. This module is using Angular2 and TypeScript 2.

I'm facing up with a trouble related with how to generate this module.

I don't know which would be the steps I would need to follow in order to generate this npm module.

I've created a [public repository on github](https://github.com/jeusdi/swagger-client).

What do I need to do in order to generate the npm module?

Comment: What problems are you having exactly.. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm not able to generate d.ts files, and I need to set `"declarations: true"` and `types: ["index.d.ts"]`. Nevertheless, any artifact is generated. I've added the changes on repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` you have set `"declarations": true`. It is supposed to be `"declaration": true`. And the `exclude` field needs to be outside `compilerOptions`. Also you are specifying that types need to be include from `index.d.ts`, When in fact there is no such file.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html.

Now in order to generate the module follow the following steps.

- Write the code for all the utilities you want to expose from your module. i.e all the entities that should be 'importable' from your module.
- Once the above step is done make a file in src(Assuming src is your `rootDir`) called index.tsx or any other name of your choice. In this file export the entities you want to expose.
- Next, in your package.json add `"main": "<outDir>/index.js"` and `"typings": <outDir>/index.d.ts`. Be sure to replace `<outDir>` with your output directory from `tsconfig`. The `main` field is used to tell the installing app where to import from when this module is referenced. For instance, If the installing app executes the following line of code

  `import {abc} from 'swagger-client'`

The `main` will tell node to look for `abc` inside the `"<outDir>/index.js"` file.
The `typings` field is just the typescript equivalent of `main` i.e. it tells node where to look for the types of `abc` in the above example.
Also notice the extensions of the files to be mentioned in the `main` and `typings` fields. They are not ts. By a rule of thumb you should not publish the `.ts` files to npm. Always commit the `.ts` files to github and publish the generated `.js`, `.d.ts` files to npm. The obvious reason for this is that by committing the generated files the module is usable in js projects as well as ts projects.

Comment: I've just changed it. It keeps generating anything. Which command are you using in order to generate artifacts?

Comment: Im using `tsc` and it keeps complaining because your tsconfig is incorrect. After fixing the tsconfig. the .d.ts files seem to be generated correctly

Comment: What do you mean by it keeps generating anything?

Comment: I've updated [tsconfig file](https://github.com/jeusdi/swagger-client/blob/master/tsconfig.json). I mean it doesnt generates me any `d.ts` file...

Comment: You are running `tsc` right? what is the version of typescript you are using. I cloned your repository and ran my globally installed typescript compiler and the dist directory was generated with the `js`, `.js.map` and .d.ts` files

Comment: `tsc -v` prints me out `Version 1.0.3.0`. Nevertheless, `npm list -g --depth=0` prints out: `typescript@2.0.10`.

Comment: if you are running tsc to compile your code then it is using version `1.0.3.0` since `tsc -v` prints that version which is a heavily outdated version of typescript. What you can do is inside your project run `npm install typescript@latest --save` and then create an npm run script in your package.json which runs tsc. Also I would suggest removing your globally installed typescript and reinstalling it because there is some mismatch in the global compiler being used and the version showed in `npm list -g --depth=0`

Comment: Thanks for all @Nahush. I've been able to generate artifacts on `dist\` folder now. `tsc` is generating me `*.d.ts`, `*.js` and `*.map` files. What do I need to do in order to generate the npm module from now on?

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :). Don't forget to upvote :P.    
(P.S I have updated the answer)

Comment: I have written a blog for this. Feel free to check it out. https://medium.com/@nahush.farkande/creating-npm-modules-written-in-typescript-8d3cb4e65783#.ba38spz0j